# RMAN Restore control file and SP File

Tags: oracle, recovery, rman

I need to perform an incomplete recovery. We keep 7 days of backups, and I want to restore the database as it was 7 days ago. I've not done this before.

My question is: I can use the SET UNTIL TIME for the restore / recovery. But, with regards to restoring the control file and SPFile........do I need to restore those separately with SET UNTIL TIME, or will RMAN be smart enough to restore everything I need based on the timeframe I set?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In general there should be no need to restore controlfile or spfile. You say '7 days of backups' but you didn't specify what type of backups, nor what your retention policy is, nor what kind of housekeeping you do. If its a vanilla inc 0 and inc 1 backups with retention policy of recovery period of 7 days or more, a simple 'set until' followed by 'restore database' followed by 'recover database' should do it